# Как правильно обновить данные в таблице MySQL?

Tags: mysql, процедуры

Помогите пожалуйста, не понимаю как сделать обновление данных в таблице.
У меня есть разные записи, некоторые из них имеют значение как директория (dir) и у них есть атрибут size (Вес файла), так же имеются файлы и путь к ним (file), надо написать запрос update, который рассчитает размер папки исходя из размеров файлов в нем.

Прилагаю пример моей базы данных (Строка с ID 91 это папка, а начиная со строки ID 129 это файлы в этой папке):
[image: Пример из базы MySQL]

Comment: Рекурсивный CTE. Сначала от корня вниз - расчёт уровня. Потом снизу вверх - суммирование размеров.